# javadoc for ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime()

Tags: java, javadoc, jodatime

The [javadoc for `org.joda.time.format.ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime()`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html#dateTime%28%29) is:

> Returns a formatter that combines a full date and time, separated by a `'T'` (`yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ`). The time zone offset is `'Z'` for zero, and of the form `'±HH:mm'` for non-zero.

It is not clear to me where the word 'zero' is pointing at/to. Zero where or what?
Is it me or is this sentence unclear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the *zero* is referring to the *time zone offset* `ZZ`. ie. for a zero time zone offset (UTC), you would use the `Z` and write `2009-11-20T11:08:00.000Z`; for +8 hours time zone offset, you would write `2009-11-20T11:08:00.000+08:00`.